# Is "would" appropriate in this case?

Tags: conditionals, would

*"If these same situations would be held by people unable to change their behaviour in order to solve or to handle them the consequences would be catastrophic."*

I know that usually the word "would" is not accepted in the protasis of the third conditional, but is there any possibility that this sentence is actually correct?

Comment: In that sentence, are you questioning the first *would*, the second, or both? I think it's fine—although it's probably more *common* to use *should* in the first instance. I also have no idea what you mean by saying that (usually) would "is not accepted." Who says that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a professional at this, but here's my opinion. I think the word "would" is correct, but I think there would be a comma after "handle them":

> "If these same situations would be held by people unable to change their behavior in order to solve or to handle them[,] the consequences would be catastrophic."